# I've added javadoc but Documentation for Main Function is not accessible offline in eclipse. why?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I've already added java api documentation and it's working well for some things like println etc but whenever I hover the mouse on java.math.BigDecimal; to see the error it says "The import java.math.BigDecimal is never used" I think the jre in my system doesn't contain the BigDecimal class. Similarly whenever I click on Main function to access the api documentation it says "The Documentation location for main(String []) has not been configured"

Comment: if you have an image please add it (correctly)

Comment: I'm a new user so first I've to get reputation 10 to upload an image.. Impossible to upload an image I think :(

Comment: whenever I hover the mouse on java.math.BigDecimal; to see the error it says "The import java.math.BigDecimal is never used" I think the jre in my system doesn't contain the BigDecimal class. Similarly whenever I click on Main function to access the api documentation it says "The Documentation location for main(String []) has not been configured"

Comment: do you actually use BigDecimal or do you just have imported it? this does not sound as if the class is not found. Is this displayed as a warning (yellow) or error (red)?

Comment: I've imported (import java.math.BigDecimal;)                                                                package c1;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecimel {

 public BigDecimel(double d) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {  
  BigDecimel bg = new BigDecimel(111); 
  
  System.out.println(bg.toString());
 System.out.println(bg);

Comment: yes it's showing a red sign.. saying "import java.math.BigDecimal is never used" and when I try to open the documentation for it, it says"location is not configured for BigDecimel class"

Comment: eclipse is sometimes a little 'unique' if you have a compiler error or warnings -  so I would resolve that _not used_ import (e.g. by actually using BigDecimal) first and then look how it looks after that.